# How to have 2 windows display different modes in the 3D Viewport

Tags: interface

I can open a new window and move it to the second monitor but it will only display the same editor screen as the original window.

How can I get it to show a different one e.g. layout on one and modelling on the other? I am running windows 10.

Sorry I should have said show OBJECT MODE in one and EDIT MODE in the other, when I click the mode button on one monitor the mode changes on both monitors

Comment: While you can detach editor windows by holding the Shift key while dragging them out, and in this way, display them on other monitors, I wouldn't think there's a way to display Object Mode and Edit Mode at the same time in any case. Due to how Blender functions on a fundamental level, it seems that we are expected to finish interacting with any one mode before interacting with another. To have two modes both displayed at once would invite the possibility of interacting with both once, which could potentially invite all manner of issues.

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can do that! I do it all the time.

When you drag out a new window, simply hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, at the same time, and that will tear that window away from the main interface! You can then move that new window to your other monitor and set it to what you like.

To change it to what you like, simply select this icon here:
[Example](https://gyazo.com/b377378d0f017d1027281454fa32be90)

Comment: Did... not... know that. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: maybe this answers that question from the other day

Comment: wow....didn't know that too! Blender is just AMAZING!!! ;)

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @TheJovialBrit dual monitor set-up

Comment: Well I have 2 monitors and a Wacom Cintiq 22HD but I don't see how having edit and object mode open at the same time would be beneficial =/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It appears that it is not possible to have an object and edit mode window open at the same time . A workaround is to have 2 edit windows open and on one of them switch off all the gizmos etc. in the material preview view, this gives a nice clear view of the editing being done on the other screen. Regards Peterrick

Answer (score 0):

In summary most likely not.

Blender apparently uses a system where, fundamentally, the modes **do not apply to the viewport itself, but the selected objects**.

This means that the viewports are just for view, but the object itself has the "data" that makes it be, for instance in *Edit Mode*, while other objects that weren't selected while changing mode remain in *Object Mode*, but are practically locked from the mode, essentially not a viewport mode but in the whole sense of the word, an object mode.

In my opinion it would make indeed more sense if instead of the data being applied to an object, it was applied as a real viewport mode; I believe this would also open the possibility of having a more "parametric approach" to all editing, like the one *3Ds Max* has, which is very practical.